# Can I use web speech api in Android browser

Tags: android, html, speech

I converted my website which includes html web speech api to an android application and my microphone doesnt work. I wanted to ask if android supports this api and if not how to combine my assets with an android mic button.

Thanks from scratch.

Comment: if you open your website in any browser inside android device you would come to know about weather it supports or not, because it totally depends upon the version of android and android do changes in the webview frequently across different versions

Comment: Or you may be post details about the versions of android that you support

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.I am using android 5.0 lollipop and over.

Comment: Have you added permission for mic?                                                                                                          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes i added it...i am sending you the other  permissions too.

Comment: add the permission for mic as RECORD_AUDIO and then check it hope it works

Comment: i hoped by adding this permission to fix the problem..i guess by adding this permission i can use mic right?

Comment: thanks a lot my friend.i ll try and post again the answer :)

Comment: welcom! you may plz upvote the comment!

Comment: You need Chrome version 55 to use speech recognition

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. My problem is not the browser. My chrome is updated and it works when i open my website on browser. The problem is that i try to build an application on android with this website and there the microphone doesnt work. Also when you open the application on facebook and you redirect to website by facebook browser microphone doesnt work. Thanks again for your help.